# How can I use a GSuite account for sending mails through node.js?

Tags: node.js, email, google-oauth, gmail-api, nodemailer

I'm creating a web application, and I want to create a mail sending functionality through Node.js (nodemailer) npm package.

1. If I can use a Gmail account, I can achieve it.
2. But I cannot use a GSuite account (example@domain.com) for sending emails.
3. I also created a service account and used (2LO authentication), but failed in making it work.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: have you allowed google use less secure app to send email?

Comment: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you can achieve this if you use a free Gmail account but not if you use a G suite account correct?

Do you receive an error message in particular?

As mentioned by  Saurabhchauhan232 in his comment it may be that you need to allow the less secure apps.

If you logged in with your G Suite account just follow this link and turn this option on -----> https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

For more guidance visit this page ---_> Less secure apps & your Google Account: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

If you don’t see this option means that first you need to allow the user to be able to turn it on from the admin console ----> Control access to less secure apps: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

Basically this option is in admin.google.com > Security > Less secure apps